# Installation in Ubuntu Docker file getting failed

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04, azure-cli

I don't have any Ubuntu machines enabled with internet and I have requirement to have a docker image ready with some basic softwares enabled as this need to be configured as our Azuredevops build agent.

So in order to work my Dockerfile , I used one of aksnode itself to build my docker image as there I could see some of the apt-get commands working somehow (may be with default internet connectivity enabled there for aks functionalities).

Below is the source.list content of aks node and I tried to copy the same to my Ubuntu based Dockerfile

```
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
```

After copying the same file to my Docker image build step as below.

```
COPY ./sources.list /etc/apt/
```

I could successfully install the basic software's like, curl wget, jq, git, python, etc...

But I am not able to install softwares like, AzureCLI, Docker, dockerce-and nodejs, chrome-headless, etc..

My dockerfile parts for them as below  as below.

```
#4-Install AzureCLI
RUN curl -LsS https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#7-install node
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN npm install


#9-install docker daemon inside docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg |  gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN echo \
   "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y
```

where all I am getting the error as below

```
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to
```

So looking for a way to get succeeded with all the above softwares installed without internet or do we have any azure archive repo for the same like other softwares enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method to provide install deb is:
In a Ubuntu machine, can access internet,

#9-install docker daemon inside docker

run:

```
sudo apt-get install \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release
```

run:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

run:

```
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

run:

```
sudo apt clean

ls /var/cache/apt/archives/

sudo apt --download-only --assume-yes install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

run

```
$ ls /var/cache/apt/archives/
containerd.io_1.6.10-1_amd64.deb
docker-ce_5%3a20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-jammy_amd64.deb
docker-ce-cli_5%3a20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-jammy_amd64.deb
docker-ce-rootless-extras_5%3a20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-jammy_amd64.deb
docker-compose-plugin_2.12.2~ubuntu-jammy_amd64.deb
docker-scan-plugin_0.21.0~ubuntu-jammy_amd64.deb
libslirp0_4.6.1-1build1_amd64.deb
pigz_2.6-1_amd64.deb
slirp4netns_1.0.1-2_amd64.deb
```

Now you can COPY /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb TO Your VM1 (no internet0
and install deb files.

2022/12/05 update

```
#Internet Host:

mkdir -p ~/WK/data
cd ~/WK
docker run -it -v ~/WK/data:/data ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash
```

do all steps in docker containers

```
cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /data/
cp /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg /data/
cp /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list /data/
# exit docker
exit
```

copy ~/WK/data to INTRANET MACHINE ~/WK/data

```
cd ~/WK
docker run -it -v ~/WK/data:/data ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash
# do all docker install step
# if error is xxx , find xxx.deb is in /data folder
# try to install xxx.deb
dpkg -i xxx.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I tried and got below error

Comment: WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libslirp0 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
             Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.57.2) but 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.9 is to be installed

Comment: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c tar zxvf /tmp/helm-v3.8.2-linux-amd64.tar.gz  && mv /linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/ && mv /tmp/kubectl /usr/local/bin/      &&  apt install /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb      &&  apt install /tmp/containerd.io_1.6.9-1_amd64.deb      &&  apt install /tmp/docker-ce-rootless-extras_20.10.9_3-0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb      &&  apt install /tmp/libslirp0_4.6.1-1build1_amd64.deb

Comment: &&  apt install /tmp/docker-ce_20.10.9_3-0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb      &&  apt install /tmp/docker-compose-plugin_2.6.0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb      &&  apt install /tmp/pigz_2.6-1_amd64.deb      &&  apt install /tmp/docker-ce-cli_20.10.9_3-0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb      &&  apt install /tmp/docker-scan-plugin_0.9.0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb      &&  apt install /tmp/slirp4netns_1.0.1-2_amd64.deb' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: solution 3: use apt-offline, which is also very cumbersome, but it should meet your needs for offline installation.

Comment: please see update 2022/12/05 in answer

Comment: by the wat, you can `docker save ubuntu:20.04 > ubuntu-20.04.tar` and copy tar file to intenet pc , run `docker load < ubuntu-20.04.tar` load docker image. You can build a image in interney pc , using docker build, then save docker image to file. then copy file. for more, you can create a private docker registry in intranet pc, you can make docker point the intranet docker registry server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
# Add this before you install any thing
RUN apt clean && apt update && apt install ca-certificates
```

Try this

```
# Maybe try add parameter `--insecure` bypass ssl
curl --insecure https://xxxxxxx
```

Why add this in a container image ? Install a docker inn a container image  ?

`RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y`

Comment: yes.. want to run docker inside docker container

Comment: I have no comment on installing docker inside the docker container.
I only provide you how to make the machine have a way to perform apt installation without Internet

Answer (score 1):

solution 3: use apt-offline

You need two machines, one connected (**VM-INTERNET**), one offline (**VM-HOSTONLY**), both machines need to install **apt-offline**.

If you want to execute `apt update`.

You have to perform the following steps:

```
VM-HOSTONLY$ sudo apt-offline set --update update-VM-HOSTONLY.sig
VM-INTERNET$ apt-offline get update-VM-HOSTONLY.sig --threads 5 --bundle update-VM-HOSTONLY.zip
VM-HOSTONLY$ sudo apt-offline install update-VM-HOSTONLY.zip
```

If you want to execute `apt-get upgrade`

You have to perform the following steps:

```
VM-HOSTONLY$ sudo apt-offline set --upgrade upgrade-VM-HOSTONLY.sig
VM-INTERNET$ apt-offline get upgrade-VM-HOSTONLY.sig --threads 5 --bundle upgrade-VM-HOSTONLY.zip
VM-HOSTONLY$ sudo apt-offline install upgrade-VM-HOSTONLY.zip
VM-HOSTONLY$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you want to execute `apt-get install`

You have to perform the following steps:

```
VM-HOSTONLY$ sudo apt-offline set install-VM-HOSTONLY-apache2.sig --install-packages apache2 libapache2-mod-php
VM-INTERNET$ apt-offline get install-VM-HOSTONLY-apache2.sig --threads 5 --bundle install-VM-HOSTONLY-apache2.zip
VM-HOSTONLY$ sudo apt-offline install install-VM-HOSTONLY-apache2.zip
VM-HOSTONLY$ sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php
```

Please note that **VM-HOSTONLY$** indicates that this instruction is executed on a **VM-HOSTONLY** machine; **VM-INTERNET$** indicates that this instruction is executed on a **VM-INTERNET** machine.

The result file generated by the execution process, such as **xxx.sig** , or **xxx.zip** needs to be copied to the corresponding machine by yourself.
But at least it can package multiple related deb files into a zip for easy copying and delivery.

**It is recommended that you test all the required files in the VM environment first, and then prepare these zip files for docker.**